# Come Near March

Tags: word-usage

can you say 'I'll contact you once again come near March' or is it 'when March comes?'? especially in a formal email to someone important.

Comment: Please reword this question so it is clear what you are asking. Put both sentences in complete form so we can know the exact wording you want.

Comment: 'Come March' means 'once March is here' and is old-fashioned / colloquial. It would sound strange, to my ears, in a formal email. I'd use 'at the beginning of March'. 'Come near March' is unidiomatic. You'd say 'towards the end of February'.

Answer (score 1):

"Come near March" is ambiguous, do you mean a short time *before* March, as in towards the end of February? Then say that instead.

> toward(s) the end of February

British English speakers tend to favour *[towards](https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/towards)* while Americans prefer *toward*.

If instead, you mean *as soon as* March comes, then say

> I'll *re-contact* you **come March**.

*Re-contact* removes the necessity of saying "again", and in my view, sounds more formal.

Interestingly, [Oxford Dictionaries](https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/come) say the preposition *come* is informal. I'm not sure I would wholly agree with that but I see no good reason why the OP should not use this word.

> *informal* PREPOSITION
>     When a specified time is reached or event happens.
>
> - *‘And, likewise, a Republican defeat now would only make them leaner and stronger **come 2008***.’
> - *‘We can only hope for a repeat performance of last week **come this weekend***.’